# Error 405 (PUT Method Not Allowed) Laravel 5.4 Resource using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

in routes.php:

```
Route::resource('/users','UserController');
```

ajax.js :

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/users",
            type:'POST',
            data:$('.edit-user-form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log('error');
                console.log(data);
                });
            }
        });
```

blade.php :

```
<form class="edit-user-form" action="/users" method="POST">
     {{ method_field('PUT') }}
     {{csrf_field()}}
.......my inputs here .....
</form>
```

Controller.php :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(['response' => 'This is POST method']);
}
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    return response()->json(['response' => 'This is PUT method']);
}
```

In POST Method it showing in console :

```
success
Object { response: "This is POST method" }
```

when i added `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` to my `form` it showing in console :

```
error
status: 405
statusText: "Method Not Allowed"
```

Please i need some help here i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the resourse route.Change the ajax request type to `PATCH`.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/users",
        type:'PATCH',
       ......
        });
```

also in the form method, change the `POST` to `PATCH`

```
<form class="edit-user-form" action="/users" method="PATCH">
     {{csrf_field()}}
.......my inputs here .....
</form>
```

Check this for [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) documentation

Comment: you can also use PUT instead of PATCH

Comment: did you check the `request` type in network tab on devtool ?

Comment: i don't understand what u mean?

Comment: press ctrl+shift+i on google chrome/firefox, go to `network` tab, see what is request type your ajax had sent

Comment: it sending but it showing in `Status` `405 Method NOT Allowed` for both `PUT` or `PATCH`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using wrong action url. Change it to

```
<form class="edit-user-form" action="{{route('users.update',$user->id)}}" method="post">
 {{csrf_field()}}
 {{method_field('PUT')}}
.......my inputs here .....
</form>


$.ajax({
        url: '{{route('users.update',$user->id)}}',
        type:'POST',
        data:$('.edit-user-form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log('error');
            console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: no it's correct, i think the problem is `AJAX` can't support the route `resource` with `update` but it's working fine with saving new records with `POST` method